# Need a counter example for tangent map preserving inner product, but F is not isometry

Tags: differential-geometry, isometry, diffeomorphism

Let $\Bbb F :\Bbb R^n\rightarrow\Bbb R^3$ is a map. And $\Bbb F_*$ be the tangent map of $\Bbb F$

If $\Bbb F$ is diffeomorphism and $\Bbb F_*$ preserves inner product, then we know that $\Bbb F$ is isometry.

Question is: If excepting one condition that $\Bbb F$ is diffeomorphism, then $\Bbb F$ can be not an isometry?

I can find example for $\Bbb F :\Bbb R^2\rightarrow\Bbb R^3$ is not isometry, but I can't find example for when domain is $\Bbb R^3$

I'm waiting for your help. Thanks

Comment: When you say diffeomorphism, you mean diffeomorphism onto its image? Is an open subset $U\subset\Bbb R^3$ sufficient for your example or do you literally mean all of $\Bbb R^3$?

Comment: I mean literally all of $\Bbb R^3$. I think the fact that plane and sphere could be example. Since they are not isometric. But I can't describe it by formally.